# Getting all of the values for a property for a list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have a class:

```
public class theclass
{
  public string a;
  public string b;
  public string c;
}
```

Yes.  It's a bad class.  Moving on.  Say I have a 100 value array of this class.  Is there a quick way with linq to get a list of strings with all of the values of b for the contents of the array?

Comment: Shouldn't you be riding a sandworm somewhere? *grin*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
TheClass[] myClasses = GetTheArray();

List<string> = myClasses.Select(c => c.B).ToList();
```

(I changed your class/property names to PascalCase, as per [coding standard convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/brada/internal-coding-guidelines))

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

```
IEnumerable<string> bValues = myArray.Select(myClass => myClass.b);
```

Comment: well if he doesn't know `Select`, he probably doesn't know `ToList` either, so it's worth including in the example.

Comment: Just started fiddling with linq, so I'm still working through things.

Answer (score 2):

```
var valuesForB = yourArray.Select((arrayMember) => arrayMember.b);
```